# Generate random 6 character lowercase string

Tags: javascript

I have seen many similar questions to this but none with quite the same criteria.

I would like to generate a short string of 6 characters that consist of lowercase letters and numbers only (ideally without the letter 'o' and the number 0).

The string has to be unique as it will be used as part of a URL. I have been using the following but the strings are similar each time they are generated and I would like them to appear very different.

```
(+new Date()).toString(36); //actually creates 8 letter string and includes o & 0
```

**Example:** Look at JS fiddle and click "save" - the url is updated with a random, unique, non sequential id. (8 characters in this case)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi tommyd456. I think that what you want is something to be done at server side, because you need to guarantee your ID to be unique. I mean, you shouldn't do this by JS in client side.

Comment: yes definitely - I agree

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this construction for generate random strings:

```
Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
```

And if improve this with `slice(0, 6)` you will get 6-char random string:

```
Math.random().toString(36).slice(2).slice(0, 6);
Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 8);
```

But you can't generate random string and be sure that this unique. Always will be chance that generated string not unique, so it's bad practice.

**UPD:** If you want use `Date`, of course, you can:

```
Date.now().toString(36).slice(0, 6);
```

And with this variant I can't guarantee that this will be unique.

If you want remove `0` and `O` then you can use smth like this:

```
Date.now().toString(36).slice(0, 6).replace(/[o,O,0]+/g, '-');
```

Here I'm replacing lowercased letter `o`, uppercased `O` and number `0` with dash. You can use what you want.

**UPD:** If you want unique values, then you don't need slice string:

```
Date.now().toString(36).replace(/[o,O,0]+/g, '-');
```

Comment: thanks - but there's no guarantee that the same string hasn't been created before is there? or am I mistaken?

Comment: is `Math.random()` based on date to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: and the zeros and o's

Comment: I'm not saying I wan't to use date - does your first example guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: @tommyd456 All answers provided here not guarantee that this will be unique. Always will be probability that random value will be duplicate. But a little chance, of course.

Comment: Yes - I think I will have to work the logic in myself as I don't think what I've asked is actually possible.

Comment: @tommyd456 see updated answer. If you will not use slice, then it will be unique.

Comment: But then there will be the "sequential feel" to the strings which is something I don't want

Comment: @tommyd456 so you need to choose :) Or unique values based on timestamp without slice. Or really random values but with a little chance of duplicate.

Comment: Think I might go for random value and do a quick DB search. If it exists I will create another.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var chars = [
  "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",
  "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",
  "k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t",
  "u","v","w","x","y","z"
];

function get6RandomChars() {
  var char1 = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)];
  var char2 = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)];
  var char3 = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)];
  var char4 = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)];
  var char5 = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)];
  var char6 = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)];

  return ""+char1+char2+char3+char4+char5+char6;
}

alert(get6RandomChars());
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jondinham/aLthx08g/

Comment: I'm not quite sure how `Math.random()` works but is there any guarantee with this code that the same string will not be produced twice?

Comment: MOST LIKELY in 1 million calls to this get6RandomChars function, you wont face the same code

Answer (score 0):

use a tiny number and pull from the right:

```
 (Math.random()/9e9).toString(36).slice(-6)
```

this gives you a lot better chance of getting different values than pulling from the left would.

if you need to avoid dupes, you'll have to memorize. a db would be good, but conceptually:

```
function rnd(){
  var r=(Math.random()/9e9).toString(36).slice(-6);
  return rnd[r] ? rnd() : ((rnd[r]=1) && r);
}
```

Comment: it has to be absolutely guaranteed that a unique string will be generated

Comment: Storing random values it's a bad practice. With time it can make overflow.

Comment: ok, see my edited answer's rnd() function. still, 2 billion combos is pretty good. going to 8 chars makes it 3 trillion...

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov: do you know of anyway else to make both un-guessable and un-repeated IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
new Date().getTime().toString(36).replace(/0,o,O/g,'').slice(-6)
```

Comment: this will still create the "sequential feel" to the strings

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
////
/// @author Nikhil Saini
/// @desc Random string generator function
/// @example var key = randomString("1-a-A-$-#-*"); gives key = 6-y-Z-<-r-@
/// @invocation randomString(pattern);
/// @param pattern: A string with random character identifiers
/// @default random identifiers:-
///     1: numerical digit,
///     a: lowercase alphabet
///     A: uppercase alphabet
///     #: alphanumeric character
///     $: special character
///     *: wildcard
///     !: lowercase alphanumeric
/// @notes:
///     1. Characters that are not acting as identifiers will be preserved
///     2. Character sets can be customised/added by setting randomStringTable.<character-identifier> to desirable string of possible characters
////

///dictionary for possible characters
var randomStringTable = {
  "1": "1234567890",
  "a": "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm",
  "A": "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM",
  "$": "~!@#$%^&*()_+`{}:\"<>?|\\[];',./-=",
  "#": "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM",
  "!": "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm",
  "*": "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM~!@#$%^&*()_+`{}:\"<>?|\\[];',./-="
};

/// function for random string generation
var randomString = pattern => {
  var randomString = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    var possibility = randomStringTable[pattern[i]];
    randomString += possibility ?
      possibility.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possibility.length)) :
      pattern[i];
  }
  return randomString;
};

console.log(randomString("aaaaaa"));
console.log(randomString("######"));
console.log(randomString("!!!!!!"));
```